# Search lowercase followed by hard return and immediately start with lowercase (REGEX)

Tags: regex

```
<content>
        <p>This</p>
        <p>is</p>
        <p>a</p>
        <p>test</p>
</content>
```

Hello, please have a look at the code above. I need to find the entries who are ending with a lowercase letter followed by a hard return and immediately start with a lowercase letter.
The code above is xml.

What have I already tried? Dozens of variations on the following code:

```
($[a-z]</p>)\n^(<p>[a-z])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which language/tool are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Tool: Schema ST4: a content managent system for creation of manuals. With regular expressions you are able to search content in the database (xml based)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. You do not match initial indentation
2. Assure you use multi-line regexps (depending on language)
3. I'm not sure if you need starting `$`

Comment: Founded, that's the syntax I need:

([a-z]<\/p>)\n^(<p>[a-z])

I removed the asterisks and I kept in mind the third tip of @mrzasa!